# how to update <select> options (value and text) using jquery

Tags: jquery

Using the jquery script below  I would like to update the following select(value and text):

```
<select id="training_field" name="training_field">
<option value="">All training fields</option>
<option value="engineering">Engineering</option>
<option value="management">Management</option>
<option value="project_management">Project Management</option>
</select>
```

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post( 'mySQL_UpdateTrainingField.php', {},
        function( data ){  // a function to deal with the returned information

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var fieldvalue = data[i];
// HERE I would like to update the value of #training_field options to data[i] and the text to data[i] as well
            }

        }, "json");
});
</script>
```

mySQL_UpdateTrainingField.php is a script that returns an array of text.

How can I do that?
I tried :

```
$('#training_field option').attr("value",fieldvalue);
$('#training_field option').text(fieldvalue);
```

but that changed all the options to the last element of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your for loop, something like this:

```
$("<option />").attr("value", yourvalue).text(yourvalue).appendTo("#training_field");
```

yourvalue equaling what the *thing* is you want to populate.